# How do we check a number is palindrome or not in its base 256 notation but without converting it to base 256?

Tags: bit-manipulation

A number is given and it has to be checked whether it is a palindrome or not in its base 256 notation. The specific problem is that it must be checked using bit manipulation, and that the leading 0 bits of the number should not considered.

Comment: Including leading zeros (fixed width) or without them, "more string-like"?

Comment: Can you please fix typo in the question? Is this part of a home work assignment/ongoing contest?

Comment: @harold it is not of any fixed length

Comment: @mukul gupta It is not of an ongoing contest. It is a practice problem:)

Comment: @DIVYAS 9 numbers on most platforms are fixed width - 16 bit, 32 bit, 64 bit, etc. The question is whether leading zeros in bitwise representation have to be considered?

Comment: @MukulGupta leading zeroes should not be considered

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the number to be a 64 bit integer and leading 0 bits to not be considered, this can be solved by finding the length of the number (base 256) and comparing each set of octet bits from start and finish.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

using namespace std;

int get_length(int64_t n) {
  int sz = 0;
  while(n) {
    n >>= 8;
    sz++;
  }
  return sz;
}

bool is_palindrome(int64_t n) {
  int64_t mask = 0xff;
  int sz = get_length(n);
  for (int i = 0, j = sz - i - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
    int left = (n & (mask << (8*i))) >> (8*i);
    int right = (n & (mask << (8*j))) >> (8*j);
    if (left != right)
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}

int main(void) {
    int64_t n;
    cin >> n;
    cout << is_palindrome(n);
    return 0;
}
```

However, in essence, this is equivalent to finding out the base 256 representation of the number but using only bitwise operators.